# Differences between MiniBatchKMeans.fit and MiniBatchKMeans.partial_fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am interested in `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans` as a way to use huge datasets. Anyway I am a bit confused about the difference between `MiniBatchKMeans.partial_fit()` and `MiniBatchKMeans.fit()`.

Documentation about [`fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.fit) states that:
*Compute the centroids on X by chunking it into mini-batches.*

while documentation about [`partial_fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.partial_fit) states that:
*Update k means estimate on a single mini-batch X.*

So, as I understand it `fit()` splits up the dataset to chunk of data with which it trains the k means (I guess the argument `batch_size` of `MiniBatchKMeans()` refers to this one) while `partial_fit()` uses all data passed to it to update the centres. The term "update" may seem a bit ambiguous indicating an initial training (using `fit()`) should have been performed or not, but judging from the example in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.fit) this is not necessary (I can use `partial_fit()` at the beginning also).

Is it true that `partial_fit()` will use all data passed to it regardless of size or is the data size bound to the `batch_size` passed as argument to the `MiniBatchKMeans` constructor? Also if `batch_size` is set to be greater than the actual data size is the result the same as the standard k-means algorithm (I guess efficient could vary in the latter case though due to different architectures).

Comment: I found a good example [on scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dict_face_patches.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dict-face-patches-py), but still trying out.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`partial_fit` is for online clustering were `fit` is for offline, however i think MiniBatchKMeans's `partial_fit` method is a little rough.

### Long explanation

I diged old PR's from the repo, and found [this one](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/132), it seems to be the first commit of this implementation, it mentions that this algorithm can implement the `partial_fit` method as a online clustering method (following the online API discussion).

So as well as the [BIRCH](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html?highlight=birch#sklearn.cluster.Birch) implementation, this algorithm uses `fit` as one time offline clustering and `partial_fit` as online clustering.

However, i did some tests comparing the [ARI](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html) of the result labels by using the fit in the entire dataset versus using partial_fit and fit in chunks, and didn't seems to get anywhere, since the ARI result were very low (~0.5), and by changing the initialization apparently the fit chunked beat partial_fit, which doesn't make sense. you can find my notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/giuliano-oliveira/513407f566529e5ee72c895c437e3658).

So my guess is, based in [this response](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/132#issuecomment-1193077) in the PR:

> I believe that this branch can and should be merged.
>
> The online fitting API (partial_fit) probably needs to mature, but I
> think that it is a bit out of scope of this work. The core
> contribution, that is a mini-batch K-means, is nice, and does seem to
> speed up things.

Is that the implementation hasn't changed much since that PR, and the partial_fit method is still a little rough, the two implementations from 2011 and now has changed (compared from the release tag), however both of them calls the function `_mini_batch_step` once in `partial_fit` (without verbose info) and calls multiple time in `fit` (with verbose info).